# Local regressions with many zeroes

Tags: nonparametric, nonlinear-regression, semiparametric

I want to run a nonparametric or semiparametric regression on data which I suspect to be non-linear. I'm using Stata for this. At first I thought of using LOWESS `lowess` and Yatchew's semiparametric regression `plreg`(https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf...867X0600600306). However, 41,329 out of 75,582 observations for my dependent variable are 0. Theoretically, this is due to a corner solution. (But, as explained by Woolridge, at least for the Tobit case, corner solutions use the same estimation procedures as censored at 0.)

I'm worried that the high amount of zeroes may be throwing off my estimation, and I would rather not simply truncate the data. I haven't been able to find an implementation that allows me to do this sort of local regression in Stata. I found an R implementation (http://ugrad.stat.ubc.ca/R/library/locfit/html/locfit.censor.html), but I'm hesitant to use it because according to "Local Regression and Likelihood" by Clive Loader, this method relies heavily on the normality assumption, but this is difficult to check because in the presence of censoring the estimated residuals are not guaranteed to be normally distributed even in large samples.

EDIT: Changed independent to dependent

Comment: You don't spell it out because the implication seems to be that your response is zero or positive. (If it can be negative, answers may differ.) If you want your regression to ignore zeros, then do that. In Stata that just needs an `if` oondition. On the other hand if zeros are legitimate or relevant values, they shouldn't be said to "throw off" the regression. The real issue may be what kind of summary you want.  Perhaps it's not a local mean or regression, but something else.  It's not data that are nonlinear, but relationships.

Comment: By referring to $0$ as a "corner value" you implicitly seem to be telling us your variable is the *dependent* variable--but you refer to it as "independent."  Is that a typo?

Comment: Yes it's a typo, sorry. It should be dependent.

Comment: I had wrongly assumed that OLS was biased in the presence of corner solutions, but upon reviewing I see that the issue lies with casual intepretation and prediction. Just to make sure, the fact that fitted values may be negative isn't a huge issue if I'm only concerned with the shape of the relationship, right?

Comment: The existence of a bounded dependent variable that in many cases achieves that bound indicates OLS is likely an inappropriate model.  What kind of measurement is your dependent variable?

Comment: Private transfers received from other households. A very similar paper to what I'm trying to do is "How widespread are nonlinear crowding out effects? The response of private transfers to income in four developing countries" by Gibson et al.